# IONIC - Upgrading to cordova-android11 from 9.1.0

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on the Ionic cordova-android upgrade to the latest(11).But while add platform I am getting below error

[Error when running ionic cordova platform add android@11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhueI.png)

I have added the few line to config.xml file.

[Added  tag to replace the old splash tag in config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IvHy.png)

[Targeting android-targetSdkVersion to 32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkFY8.png)

Also while build the app with ionic cordova build android I am getting this error

[build error for ngModule decorator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnc8I.png)

Please let me know if I am missing something here.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of breaking changes when upgrading cordova-android and also when you update your target SDK. I would highly discourage doing all of them at once. What I would do instead is update them one by one. and read the update docs carefully (also the ones for the minor and patch updates):

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2022/07/12/cordova-android-release-11.0.0.html
And also the docs for the minor version updates.

I don't remember this specific error, but are what JDK are you using. One of the breaking changes is that you have to update from 8 to 11. That might be this one. But again, you will just get a different error when you've solved this one. There are too many breaking changes to do them all at once.